# How can I show the content of a LIFO stack without deleting the content in Java?

Tags: java, stack, lifo

I'm trying to create a 'history' kind of feature that follows the LIFO characteristics. Last Input First Output.

So the user will introduce some words that will be stored in a stack for printing them afterwords. The program, summarized, looks like this:

```
Stack<String> history = new Stack<>();
String word = null;

while (!word.equals(exit)) {

   word = scan.nextLine();

   if (word.equals(show)) {
   
      showHistory();
   } else {
   
     history.push(word);
   }
}
```

And `showHistory();` function have this format:

```
for (String i : history) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The issue is, when I execute this, the output I get it's the words the user might have introduced but in a FIFO format. For example, if the user introduces:

> Pencil
>
> Book
>
> Shirt

The output this program shows is:

> Pencil
>
> Book
>
> Shirt

But the output I want, following the LIFO format is:

> Shirt
>
> Book
>
> Pencil

I also don't want to delete the data the stack is storing in any point of the execution, so I don't want to use `history.pop();` because, if I'm not wrong, that would delete the data in the stack.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you yould create a helper stack which can hold the popped items temporarily:

```java
Stack<String> temp = new Stack<>();
while(!history.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(history.peek());
    temp.push(history.pop);
}
while(!temp.isEmtpy){
    history.push(temp.pop);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to use any Java class, you could use a Deque instead of a Stack? The iterator() and descendingIterator() methods would do your work.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

From the Stack documentation: A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

Answer (score 0):

if you want inverse order, just do it

```
for (ListIterator  i = history.listIterator(history.size()); i.hasPrevious();) {
    System.out.println(i.previous());
}
```